# Display 5 most recent forum posts

Tags: php

So I have 3 tables inside of my database, let's say 1_comments, 2_comments and 3_comments and I want to display the latest 5 posts of all 3 tables at once in PHP and sort by the most recent time. My code is:

```
<?php
  $row="";

  $link = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
  mysql_select_db("database");
  $query = "SELECT * from 1_comments  ORDER by timestamp DESC limit 5";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>".$row['comment']."</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
  } 

  mysql_close($link);
?>
```

So it's taking the most recent 5 posts from the comments row on 1_comments and sorting them by their most recent timestamp, but I can't seem to get it working for 1_comments, 2_comments and 3_comments all at once.

Comment: Please show the code where you attempted to get it to work with the other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all tables have the same structure you can use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

Something like:

```
(SELECT * from 1_comments  ORDER by timestamp DESC limit 5)
UNION
(SELECT * from 2_comments  ORDER by timestamp DESC limit 5)
UNION
(SELECT * from 3_comments  ORDER by timestamp DESC limit 5)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 5
```

However, I would take a good look at the database structure and try to reduce the 3 similar tables to just one.